# Accessing membership information in webform

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

On a webform that uses an Existing Contact and a membership then the existing membership info is loaded by the webform and displayed at the top of the form in the messages block.  Eg: 'Full Member membership for My Org has a status of "Current". Expires March 31st, 2019.'

Is there a way to access this information that webform is retrieving? I'd like to use the status or expiration date in a conditional.

Comment: are you coming from a View and hence could add mid, then you should get that data available in fields.